# Issue with CFBundleIdentifier Collision

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, watchkit, provisioning-profile

I have an issue with iTunes Connect. When I transferred my application with watch support to another apple account after I've received an error from iTunes Connect when I tried to upload an ipa file (that was signed by new account after transferring) to.

I was transferring the applications very often and have no any problems before. Problems are for watch kit application and watch kit extension only, a main application is ok.

Have same problems for another 3 my applications with watch support which were transferred to new account. A transferring the applications without watch support is working as expected without any issue.

ps.
All mobileprovision files for transferred applications were either transferred too or recreated into a new account (old account doesn’t have any transferred bundle ids and mobile provision files with after).

Any ideas?
Thank you.
Sorry, english is not my native language.

> Description of an error from Apple
>
> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "My application name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> CFBundleIdentifier Collision - The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.my.company.watchkitextension' of 'My application name.app/PlugIns/My application name WatchKit Extension.appex' is already in use by another application.
>
> CFBundleIdentifier Collision - The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.my.company.watchkitapp' of 'My application name.app/PlugIns/My application name WatchKit Extension.appex/My application name WatchKit App.app' is already in use by another application.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

**Updated**

The problem has been solved. I've just transferred the applications to the third my company's Apple account without any problems

Comment: The problem has been solved. I've just transferred the applications to the third my company's Apple account without any problems.

Comment: Please write above comment as answer.